# Adding more than one directory to perform searches

Tags: python

Is it possible to add more than one directory to `source= [`?

I need to look for certain files on a set in different directories in order to move them to specific folders afterwards. Any ideas?

When using only one folder for source, it works, but when I add a second one nothing shows as results although both folders contain files with that name.

`````
import os, shutil

source = [
    "r\\ABC\A",
    "r\\ABC\B"
]

set = {
"AC1",
"AC2"
       }

for file in source:
    for x in set:
        if file.__contains__("FF"): continue
        else:
            if file.__contains__(str(x)):
                print(file)
````
`````

Comment: don't name variable as special keywords, also it;s wont print anything as AC1 is not present in source values

Comment: Well, it does work when I use only one folder for source...

Comment: you are just checking if  "`r\\ABC\A" `contains `AC1` or not , if yes then print it, clearly it is not using it. also instead of this `if file.__contains__("FF")` use `if "FF"  in file` , better not use private functions

Answer (score 0):

you aren't escaping your second `\`...

```
source = [
    "r\\ABC\\A",
    "r\\ABC\\B"
]
```

Comment: It's a mapped network drive, that's why it's supposed to be \\ on the beginning only. I tried it, didn't work :(